# Execution failure when using @Autowired annotation in Spring app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have two classes, `ErpDataRepository` and `RequestProcessingService`. I want to autowire the "Request" class and did so in the "ErpDataRepo" class below.

However, when I added that line, my Spring app crashes with an error that the command:

> failed with non-zero exit value 1

My understanding is that it's crashing because Spring cannot find the classes that I defined as a component or service. However, I've already added the `@Service` annotation to the `RequestProcessingService` class and Spring still can't detect it. I also checked the `@ComponentScan` in my configuration class and it should be able to find the classes that I've set for it.

Any ideas as to why this error is happening?

**ErpDataRepository** class

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
public class ErpDataRepository extends BaseRepository implements IAccountingObjectTypeRepository {

    private static final int DELETE_ALL_FOR_TYPE_PAGE_LIMIT = 1500;

    protected DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
    protected AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;

    @Autowired
    private RequestProcessingService requestProcessingService;

    public ErpDataRepository(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB, DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper) {
        super(EcpConstants.ERP_DATA_TABLE, EcpConstants.DATA_COMPANY_ID_ERP_ID_INDEX, dynamoDBMapper, amazonDynamoDB);
        this.dynamoDBMapper = dynamoDBMapper;
        this.amazonDynamoDB = amazonDynamoDB;
    }
}
```

**RequestProcessingService** class

```
@Service
@CustomLog
public class RequestProcessingService {
    @Autowired
    private ProcessingErrorRepository processingErrorRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ErpDataRepository erpDataRepository;

    public PaginatedDataResponse<ProcessingError> getProcessingErrors(String requestId) throws NotFoundException {
        return getProcessingErrors(requestId, EcpConstants.DEFAULT_NEXT_PAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is cyclic dependency in your code as you have autowired RequestProcessingService into ErpDataRepository and into RequestProcessingService you autowired  ErpDataRepository so it seems like-

```
RequestProcessingService
    |                 ^
    |                 |
ErpDataRepository     |
    |.                |
    |_________________|
```